# SelectOneMenu does not display list items

Tags: jsf, primefaces

EDIT

Here is a generic example that I recreated
I am using JSF2.3 and primefaces 6.2.2

I have 3 SelectOneMenu Components (Country, State, City) that I am trying to populate from a MySql database. The problem is that when I persist for example, country (USA) and in the same session, when I try to add a state, the selectOneMenu list (Country list) does not show the just persisted country value in the drop down list.

The backing bean is @ViewScoped which I think is the issue. But, I feel that this is the right scope. I also noticed that the @PostConstruct init() method is not called just before the dialog is displayed which is the right behavior for a bean with @ViewScoped. It gets called at the beginning of the session.
Not sure if there is an event that I need to look at. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't know anything abut JSF and sorry if I'm wasting your time with this comment, but from what I'm understanding, there might be a problem with getting the list data upon refresh after the submit. Are you sure you're loading all of the data the same way, after submitting it, like you do when the application is started?

Comment: I am not even able to select any items from the list as they are empty.

Comment: Let me try to get this right. When you open the application for the first time is it loading everything correctly? Does everything work?

Comment: when I first start up the db is empty and I add, lets say 2 portfolios which is persisted to the database. After that, I add 2 accounts for each portfolio. Now after that when I try to add an asset to an account is when I have an issue - I dont see any items in the dropdown list. I also noticed that when I try to add an asset it does not go into the init() method - which is strange - probably because it is @ViewScoped

Comment: Please edit your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Check [this](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html) out. It might give you an idea of what's happening.

Comment: Doombringer, thanks for the link. I have seen this and actually used this link as a guide to model.

Comment: [mcve] being a without classes, just nested hashmaps, no dialogs, no separators etc...

Comment: Hi, your edit does not make it a [mcve]... please do, it is something you should always do when having problems and when plain debugging does not help. Your question is impossible to answer. Please also read http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: You are not improving your question by your edits